# .htaccess setting non allow mobile devices to play .mp3

Tags: php, android, .htaccess

Have an mp3 player and need to make in case of someone tried to direct access (download) mp3 or ogg files in my server/folder, to deny it for all.

Already tested this code, all is alright, only it didn't work for mobile phones:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp3|ogg)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

How can I get mobile devices to play .mp3 files?

Comment: HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed and many browsers also don't send it at all. Use the Files directive and `deny from all` and then maybe use PHP to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Will this suffice?

```
<Files  ~ "\.mp3$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Did I have it add to existing code above or I have to remove it? And where is deny for .ogg files??